# The Luminosity of two stars with same brightness but at different PC away

Tags: fundamental-astronomy

Stars A and B are both equally bright as seen from Earth, but A is 120 pc away while B is 24 pc away. Which star has the greater luminosity? How many times brighter is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute luminosity of A is bigger than B. Like two lamps.
$$\frac{120}{24}=5,$$
so A is five times farther B, but as the luminosity decays with the square of the distance, then  A is $5^{2}=25$ times more luminous.

Comment: Where did you get the 24?

Comment: Nevermind! I'm sorry, I'm overthinking. This makes since and is much simpler to understand this way.

Comment: I was trying to use the Inverse Square Law which is much harder to understand.

Comment: James, you might also like to read Wikipedia's page on [absolute magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_magnitude) which is about being able to compare the luminosity of stars at different distances. :-)